# free tool for multiple dvd copies on windows?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

My sister was recently married and had a copy of the wedding video provided to her on dvd

She'd like to include a copy in 'thank you' gifts to guests. She's looking to make approximately 20 copies of her original dvd. Unfortunately her PC was not bundled with nero or roxio, so I'm looking for free software on windows that will facilitate that.

She's a neophyte, so as few clicks as possible to accomplish her goal would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) always served me for such purposes. Although pretty much any of the more popular programs will do you fine.

Btw, did you know that Nero [recently introduced stripped down freeware CD and DVD burner.](http://lifehacker.com/#!5326520/nero-introduces-stripped+down-freeware-cd-and-dvd-burner)

Comment: free nero? sold! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) for years for all things CD/DVD related and love it. Sounds like you just want to either Make an ISO and burn a bunch, here is a link to how in their forums http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=6380.

Comment: ImgBurn is good.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

Time limited software (demo, you get something like 30 days of usage):

- Blindwrite - http://www.vso-software.fr/products/Blindwrite/blindwrite.php

Free Software (not certain if writing works without having Nero or such installed - check it out first)

- DVD Decrypter - http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/

You could certainly use DVD Decrypter to make an ISO of the original DVD and then use (if you have Windows 7 [or possibly Vista?]) use the Windows built-in image burning software.

Answer (score 0):

DVDx 4.0 free and open source [DVDx Official website](http://www.labdv.com/dvdx/)
More info on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdx/)

And Also would you kindly pass my congratulations and wishes for a life of happiness to your sister